# memory cache is too high and going to use swap

Tags: linux, centos, memory, java, cache

i have a centos server with 32 g RAM
and the state of it, is (free -m):

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
 Mem:         32071      31488        583          0        244      19329
 -/+ buffers/cache:      11914      20157
 Swap:        17399        287      17112
```

the cached size is growth 
(between every restart app and clear cache)

after 5 hours that i post my question the memory status is :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         32071      31850        221          0        194      20124
-/+ buffers/cache:      11530      20541
Swap:        17399        299      17100
```

my java options is :

```
-Xms12g -Xmx12g -XX:MaxNewSize=6g -XX:NewSize=6g -XX:+UseParallelOldGC -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+UseTLAB -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=15 -XX:+DisableExplicitGC
```

as you see, cache size is too high and in the high load time on my server, the swap is used and the server is too slow (Unlike https://www.linuxatemyram.com/ , the memory is full and swap is used and my app is too slow)

i used java for service.

what can i do?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/157793

Comment: Hmm, have you monitorized the use of the different types of memory of Java?. You should reconsider the options about GC, memory and log of your java application. A java application can be slowed down by a non optimal configuration of the memory

Comment: thanks for your reply but my problem is about swap using beacuse of memory cache growth and i can not find what process use this cache

Comment: i dont know how to see java cache usage. can you help me ?

Comment: the top command show virtual memory is highly used by java (unlike physical memory) and my free -m command is like above. i can not find the problem

Comment: Have you even established that your application is "slow" due to memory issues? The `free` output you show doesn't signal any problem with the Linux memory management, there is only a tiny amount of swap used (which is perfectly normal) and most likely, what is swapped out is *not* your app.

Comment: I suggest forgotting at this moment about cache usage. You can see how it grows simply opening (and closing) a large file and that does not mean that paging is started. Now, please share your java configuration and consider adding -Xloggc, -XXHeadDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, --XX:+PrintGCDetails, --XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution.

Comment: @elham.jahani: Edit your post to add information, don't try to post it just as a comment.

Comment: In order to discard (or not) GC issues, I suggest including .verbose:gc, -Xloggc:/var/tmp/gc.log and --XX:+PrintGCDetails. Then, by examining the log, you could see how often Full GC is entering (never is a good period), and how good are the parameters you are using. Please consider also using tools to monitorize in real time the memory.

Comment: Anyway, as @Sven has pointed, your configuration discards swapping (at least, swapping due to the java application). You are using, as maximum,  6GB in your Java application out of 32 GB available in your server. And, even GC is ever the pricipal suspect, there are others (connections with DB, thread usage, etc.)

Comment: This is not very readable. I put my next provisional observations in an answer. Of course that cannot be considered as a definitive one as it depends of the results of tests

Comment: I don’t think swapping is your problem, but you can verify this with vmstat sor sar to see how many paging is actually going on. You can reduce the swappiness of the Linux Kernel if you really care.

Answer (score 1):

Reasons by which a Java application in a server can be slowed are only limited by our imagination (and sometimes by Providence). Memory greedy processes are part of them, the memory exhaustion they cause implies swapping and the interaction with disk kills the performance.

However, in this case, the memory usage does not show symptoms of swapping (see comment of @Sven). It is more plaussible an explication based on the behaviour of the application.

Java applications are very sensitive (among other things) to memory configuration. Programmers are very happy in Java (and in almost all of modern languages) because they do not have to call free functions to avoid memory leaks,  as that is done by the Garbage Collector. However, the Garbage Collector can freeze the application when it enters. There are various types of garbage collections. The ones acting on the new zone are less invasive, those in the old zone are worse and full gc are the worst.

In general (and of course in this case) it would be necessary to study the memory evolution in order to optimize its configuration. Anyway, we can see some points upon which to reflect:

- The memory assigned to the application is 12 GB out of 32 GB of the total space of the server.
- The space assigned to new objects is 4 GB out of 12 GB. As you can see in [Heap Tuning Parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19900-01/819-4742/abeik/index.html), It means a NewRatio of 2, conform to best practices. Anyway, inncreasing this value should be considered.

> The NewSize and MaxNewSize parameters control the new generation’s minimum and maximum size. Regulate the new generation size by setting these parameters equal. The bigger the younger generation, the less often minor collections occur. The size of the young generation relative to the old generation is controlled by NewRatio. For example, setting -XX:NewRatio=3 means that the ratio between the old and young generation is 1:3, the combined size of eden and the survivor spaces will be fourth of the heap.
>
> By default, the Application Server is invoked with the Java HotSpot Server JVM. The default NewRatio for the Server JVM is 2: the old generation occupies 2/3 of the heap while the new generation occupies 1/3. The larger new generation can accommodate many more short-lived objects, decreasing the need for slow major collections. The old generation is still sufficiently large enough to hold many long-lived objects

Anyway, the use of other resources (threads, pools, connections, etc.) should not be dismissed.

Comment: thanks for your reply. my bad, Information about java OPT entered incorrectly and now i edit it.

Comment: Ok. I will re-edit the answer, pointing only the NewRatio importance

Comment: is that config effect on cache memory usage? after 5 hours (that i ask my question) the cache is 20139 and my free mem is 196

Comment: You probably are question yourself, why these guys seem dismiss the cache log when it is clear as water?. Well, I understand you distrust me (a newcomer here though probably I could be your father, but yo do not know it), It is more difficult to see why you consider @Sven (76.937 points of reputation at the moment of this comment) not very trusty. Cache suggests that policies with you logs are definitely improvable, but in the queue of suspects, you should put it after the third page. Please, empty the cache (stopping the app if you can), do vmstat before and after doing vi <hugefile> and see

Comment: sorry, i'm just new in java and I do not know much about gc and ..., thanks :(

Answer (score 0):

You have not explained by how much your system is too slow and where (interactive users? batch processing?)  and only identified one performance counter, memory. This will not find your problem. Be methodical in collecting response time and monitoring data, and digging into how the application and operating system work.

One good starting point on a Linux box is [Linux Performance Analysis in 60,000 Milliseconds](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/linux-performance-analysis-in-60-000-milliseconds-accc10403c55). CPU, storage, network, errors, and of course memory.

```
uptime
dmesg | tail
vmstat 1
mpstat -P ALL 1
pidstat 1
iostat -xz 1
free -m
sar -n DEV 1
sar -n TCP,ETCP 1
top
```

You can get deep visibility into an application by profiling it. Give [Java in Flames](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/java-in-flames-e763b3d32166) a read (also happens to be a Netflix tech blog). The `-XX:+PreserveFramePointer` option allows Java stacks be associated with OS profiling.